# Drawing U shaped node around another node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw the following image using tikz.

[image: caching]

Is there an easy way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? You are more likely to get effective help if you post code for a small document people can start from. Can you at least draw the inside node? Note that if you really want a U-shaped node, that is hard. If you just want something which looks like that, it is easy - just lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [crf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) said, you probably do not want to use a `node` shape for the *U*, this would be quite complex. What you can do, however, is to exploit `nodes` to get the shape correct:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            workerWidth/.style={minimum width=3cm},
            workerHeight/.style={minimum height=2cm},
            UWidth/.style={minimum width=1cm},
            every node/.style={
                text centered,
                },
            thick
            ]
        \node[workerWidth, workerHeight, draw] (worker) at (0, 0) {Worker};

        \node[anchor=north, workerWidth, yshift=-0.5cm] (cache) at (worker.south) {Cache};

        \node[anchor=east, workerHeight, UWidth, xshift=-1cm] (left) at (worker.west) {};
        \node[anchor=west, workerHeight, UWidth, xshift=1cm] (right) at (worker.east) {};

        \draw (left.north west) -- (left.west |- cache.south) -- (right.east |- cache.south) -- (right.north east) -- (right.north west) -- (right.west |- cache.north) -- (left.east |- cache.north) -- (left.north east) -- cycle;

        \draw[<-, >={Latex}] (left.west) -- ++(-1, 0);
        \draw[->, >={Latex}] (left.east) -- (worker.west);
        \draw[->, >={Latex}] (worker.east) -- (right.west);
        \draw[->, >={Latex}] (right.east) -- ++(1, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is quite like your image:
[image]

To get a better idea how it works, I coloured the helping `nodes`:
[image]

From these three `nodes` it uses their base anchors to construct the *U* shape, while styles ensure, that all `nodes` are of the correct size (you could do this manually for every node, but this way is ensures consistency).

---

If you nevertheless really want a *U*-shaped node, you will probably have to provide more information and give some starting code. That stuff is quite complex.